# There is a error when I want to run `node-gyp rebuild`

Tags: node-gyp

Environment：Windows10 x64， nodejs v8.15.0  python：2.7.6

I want to rebuild my code, and the last step is `node-gyp rebuild`.

I get an error:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Failed to load Visual C++ component “VCBuild.exe”。To fix this,1) Install .NET Framework 2.0 SDK；2) Install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005；or 3) If the component is installed in a different location, add its location to the system path. [C:\Other Soft\AMO-Tools-Suite-develop\build\binding.sln]
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Failed to load Visual C++ component “VCBuild.exe”。To fix this,1) Install .NET Framework 2.0 SDK；2) Install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005；or 3) If the component is installed in a different location, add its location to the system path. [C:\Other Soft\AMO-Tools-Suite-develop\build\binding.sln]
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Failed to load Visual C++ component “VCBuild.exe”。To fix this,1) Install .NET Framework 2.0 SDK；2) Install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005；or 3) If the component is installed in a different location, add its location to the system path. [C:\Other Soft\AMO-Tools-Suite-develop\build\binding.sln]
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Failed to load Visual C++ component “VCBuild.exe”。To fix this,1) Install .NET Framework 2.0 SDK；2) Install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005；or 3) If the component is installed in a different location, add its location to the system path. [C:\Other Soft\AMO-Tools-Suite-develop\build\binding.sln]
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Failed to load Visual C++ component “VCBuild.exe”。To fix this,1) Install .NET Framework 2.0 SDK；2) Install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005；or 3) If the component is installed in a different location, add its location to the system path. [C:\Other Soft\AMO-Tools-Suite-develop\build\binding.sln]
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Failed to load Visual C++ component “VCBuild.exe”。To fix this,1) Install .NET Framework 2.0 SDK；2) Install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005；or 3) If the component is installed in a different location, add its location to the system path. [C:\Other Soft\AMO-Tools-Suite-develop\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\18363\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\18363\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Other Soft\AMO-Tools-Suite-develop
gyp ERR! node -v v8.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I tried to fix it with:

`npm config set msvs_version 2017 -global`

and:

`npm install -global -production windows-build-tools`

But it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try the obvious? It is in the error message: To fix this,1) Install .NET Framework 2.0 SDK；2) Install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005；or 3) If the component is installed in a different location, add its location to the system path.

Answer (score 0):

```
g++ gcc libgcc libstdc++
```

You shall install above tools.

Comment: I am install the VS2017 and git

Comment: @L.Guo No you need to install gcc compilers not git.